# shortest way to get first char from every word in a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I want a shortest way to get 1st char of every word in a string in C#.

what I have done is:

```
string str = "This is my style";
string [] output = str.Split(' ');
foreach(string s in output)
{
   Console.Write(s[0]+" ");
}

// Output
T i m s
```

I want to display same output with a shortest way...

Thanks

Comment: Well, that is pretty much the shortest way.

Comment: I actually don't see anything wrong with this method.  It's readable and does what it says on the box.  Why do you want shorter?  Just because something is shorter does not mean it is readable or obvious to what you are doing.  What you have here doesn't even need commenting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
string str = "This is my style"; 
str.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i[0] + " "));
```

Comment: Using `Array.ForEach(str.Split(' '), s => Console.Write(s[0] + " "));` would be slightly shorter and faster. You might also want to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to handle the situation where the string starts with a space or contains consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 24):

```
var firstChars = str.Split(' ').Select(s => s[0]);
```

If the performance is critical:

```
var firstChars = str.Where((ch, index) => ch != ' ' 
                       && (index == 0 || str[index - 1] == ' '));
```

The second solution is less readable, but loop the string once.

Comment: Use `.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead to avoid errors on multiple spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Print first letter of each word in a string

```
string SampleText = "Stack Overflow Com";
string ShortName = "";
SystemName.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => ShortName += i[0].ToString());
```

Output:

```
SOC
```

Comment: string SampleText = "Stack Overflow Com";
string ShortName = "";
SampleText .Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => ShortName += i[0].ToString());

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions could be the answer:

```
  Regex.Matches(text, @"\b(\w{1})")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked better then the others and still very flexible:

```
string.Join("", str.Split(" ").Select(x => x[0]).ToArray())
```

Comment: how this is better than the others if is the same answer but with a join?

Comment: @Leandro:  it's better for 'simple folk' like me who are searching for a method to get an abbreviation for a name (John Doe => JD). But you're correct, in the essence of the question, there is nothing new or better.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is perfectly fine, but if you want better performance you can try:

```
string str = "This is my style";
Console.Write(str[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if(str[i-1] = " ")
        Console.Write(" " + str[i]);
}
```

You might get a lower constant factor with this code but it still runs in O(n). Also, I assume that there will never be more than one space in a row and it won't start with space.

If you want to write less code you can try:

```
str result = str.Split(" ").Select(y => y[0]).ToList();
```

Or something.

Comment: You will have a problem if the string starts with ' '.

Comment: Yep... I added a reservation note for that.

Answer (score 0):

I work it with a list using LukeH consideration.

```
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            Array.ForEach(str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), s => output.Add(s));
```