# Need RegEx to get the first character of two strings regardless of what character type it is

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got a c# snippet that takes a string from a model (CustomerName), and replaces the full name with just the initials. So "John Doe" = "JD". It works great. Problem is, numbers and special chars throw it off. So "1234 4321" = "1234 4321". Or "#John Doe" = "#John Doe".

I need help in tweaking the code so it does the first char in both halves of the string REGARDLESS of the char type.

So, "#John Doe" I would want "#D". "1234 4321" I would want "14"

```
  var initials = new Regex(@"(\b[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]* ?");
        model.Customerinitials = initials.Replace(model.CustomerName, "$1");
```

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "both halves"? What would you expect to happen with "John_Doe" or "John.Doe" for example? Or what about "Abc Def Ghi"? What about emoji, which take two UTF-16 code units (`char` in C#) to represent? The more precise you can be about the requirements, the easier it will be to implement and test.

Comment: What are the expected results for the several inputs you provided?

Comment: Edited post to show the expected results. This isnt fully freeform - there are a few rules about the initial string, such as it will ALWAYS have two "halves" and these halves will always be separated by no more than one whitespace. So "Whatever Whatever", not "Whatever Whatever Whatever" or "Whatever      Whatever"

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful [shortest way to get first char from every word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713444/shortest-way-to-get-first-char-from-every-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this snippet

```
var initials = new Regex(@"(.).*?(\s|$)+");
model.Customerinitials = initials.Replace(model.CustomerName, "$1");
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hdPsvE/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you but this regex would capture the first char and the first char after a white space

`^(.)\S+\s(.)`